# Callback is not defined in module.exports

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have a route like

```
var helper = require('./helper');

router.get('/create', function(req, res, next){
    helper.saveItem('itemId', function(err) {
        if(err) {
            return next(err);
        }
        next();
    });
});
```

and in helper helper.js

```
module.exports = {
    saveItem: function(id, callback) {
        var item = new ItemModel({Id: id});
        item.save().exec(callback);
    },
}
```

When I call saveItem, the 'id' parameter has the right value, but the callback is undefined. And I can not figure it why.

Comment: Are you sure you posted same code? may be some typo in variable name. Like not latin `c` in `callback`

Comment: Try `console.log(arguments)` inside `saveItem`

Comment: I did console.log and I get the right value for id and undefined for callback. I checked for typos, copy/paste the parameter name..

Comment: from where `helper.js` knows what is `ItemModel`?

Comment: In provided code you obviously provide second argument as function. There is nothing wrong here. Check twice what code actually calls `saveItem`.

Comment: @Krzystof
This is not the whole code. It is a large file. ItemModel is provided. The point is that the callback is undefined.

Comment: @Peter you've probably tried this but do you get `undefined` in `saveItem` or in `exec` function?

Comment: Tested your code in an express application shell. No issues found, at least the error is not in code shared by you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this code . Instead of giving exec method pass callback directly in save method.

```
module.exports = {
    saveItem: function(id, callback) {
        var item = new ItemModel({Id: id});
        item.save(callback);
    },
}
```

Comment: This works. Thanks. 

callback is still undefined when I console.log it in saveItem, but it gets executed correctly. Weird.

Comment: can you send your code .because its working fine for me even console.log is printing function